# c# Activator.CreateInstance does not initialize vars

Tags: c#, .net, createinstance

Having `Remember.cs`:

```
namespace Tasks
{
    public class Remember : Task
    {
        new public string name = typeof(Remember).Name;
        new public Task.Priority priority = Task.Priority.High;
    }
}
```

`Task.cs`:

```
public abstract class Task
{
    public string name;
    public Task.Priority priority = Task.Priority.Low;

    public enum Priority
    {
        High = 3,
        Medium = 2,
        Low = 1,
    }
}
```

When i create an instance of this class by using:

```
Task task = (Task)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Remember));
Debug.Log(task.name + " - " + task.priority);
```

Task's name is null and priority is the lowest number available in `Task.Priority` enum rather than the selected one (High).

Why does `Activator.CreateInstance` not initialize those vars?

Comment: What makes you think this has anything to do with `Activator.CreateInstance`? You should see the same with `Task task = new Remember();`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are re-declaring the variables in your subclass (via the `new` keyword), which gives you a separate set of variables than your `Task` class. Instead, you should set the `Task` variables directly from the constructor of the `Remember` class.

```
namespace Tasks
{
    public class Remember : Task
    {
        public Remember()
        {
            name = typeof(Remember).Name;
            priority = Task.Priority.High;
        }
    }
}
```

As others have pointed out, this has nothing to do with `Activator.CreateInstance`. You get the same behavior when you use `new Remember()`.